# Spring Websecurity throwing 401 on 'ignored' resource when throwing an exception in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application setup, using SpringSecurity and OneLogin as the JWT token provider.

The WebConfig class looks like this:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers(
            "/actuator/info",
            "/actuator/health",
            "/someArbitraryPath/**");
    }
}
```

So far, so good, all endpoints except the above ones are secured and only work when passing in a (valid) JWT token. The ones configured above seem to work when not passing in an authentication header at all, which is exactly what I intend to do.

Except... when one of both calls under "/someArbitraryPath/someDto/" throws an exception, which is configured to return a ResponseStatus "NOT_FOUND", I get a 401 as a result.

So, under "/someArbitraryPath", I have the following (open to the public) REST Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/someArbitraryPath")
public class SomeArbitraryApiController {
    private final SomeArbitraryService service;
    private final SomeArbitraryDtoMapper dtoMapper;

    public SomeArbitraryApiController(SomeArbitraryService service, SomeArbitraryDtoMapper dtoMapper) {
        this.service = service;
        this.dtoMapper = dtoMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/someDtosList", params = {"page", "size"})
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public SomePageDto getSomeDtoPage(
                @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int page,
                @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "250") int size) {
        Page<SomeObject> someDtoPage = service.searchPageOfSomeObjects(page, size);
        List<SomeDto> someDtoList = dtoMapper.someObjectsToDtos(someDtoPage.getContent());
        PageDto pageDto = new PageDto(size, someDtoPage.getTotalElements(), someDtoPage.getTotalPages(), page);
        return new SomePageDto(someDtoList, pageDto);
    }

    @GetMapping("/someDtosList/{dtoId}")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public SomeDto getSomeDtoById(@PathVariable(value = "dtoId") String dtoId) {
        return dtoMapper.objectToDto(
                service.getSomeObjectById(dtoId)
        );
    }
}
```

The last call of both, the one retrieving a specific SomeDto object, can throw a ResourceNotFoundException, which is configured to return a ResponseStatus NOT_FOUND:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public ResourceNotFoundException(String resourceName, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
        super(String.format("%s not found with %s : '%s'", resourceName, fieldName, fieldValue));
    }
}
```

This, however, does NOT return a 404 HTTP Status when calling this unsecured - this returns me a 401 Unauthorized:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

However, when I explicitly catch the exception in my RestController and set the Response status on the HttpServletResponse object to

```
response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND);
```

then I do get a 404. But not the one I would like to (and I wouldn't want to re-configure the same error object, would I).

When I call this endpoint with a valid JWT token, it does return me the correct 404 error with correct body.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A deep dive intro DEBUG logs further and I have found the issue.

When throwing an exception with a HTTP_STATUS code, Spring actually redirects to /error. So that endpoint had to be added to the ignored endpoints for security.

```
2019-04-18 15:47:36,950 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={} 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,958 DEBUG o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error] 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,962 DEBUG o.a.catalina.core.StandardWrapper -   Returning non-STM instance 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,962 DEBUG s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping - looking up handler for path: /error 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,968 DEBUG s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping - looking up handler for path: /error 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,968 DEBUG s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping - looking up handler for path: /error 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,969 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/v2/api-docs' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,969 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/swagger-resources/configuration/ui' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,969 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/swagger-resources' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,969 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/swagger-resources/configuration/security' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,969 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/swagger-ui.html' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,969 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/webjars/**' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,970 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,970 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,970 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,970 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET] 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST] 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT] 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE] 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters. 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request. 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter - No token in request, will continue chain. 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,971 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,972 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,973 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@c875a1a4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,973 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,973 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,973 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,974 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /error; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(authenticated)] 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,974 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@c875a1a4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,979 DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@789f882a, returned: -1 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,982 DEBUG o.s.b.a.a.listener.AuditListener - AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-04-18T13:47:36.981Z, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}] 
2019-04-18 15:47:36,982 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point 
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks a lot for the pointer in the right direction, dur!